# Is there a utility/tool that will extract Git comments into a nice release notes document?

Tags: git, version-control, visual-studio-2017, release-notes

I would like to extract Git comments of a specific application branch into a formatted release notes for a specific application version.

I can extract it to a text file or copy the revision history from VS2017 to Excel, but it requires some additional cleaning and filtering.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "cleaning and filtering"? Can you show an example?

Comment: By "git comments" do you mean `git log` messages? Can you give an example of the comments you have and the release notes you'd like to see?

Comment: For instance, Merge messages I want to avoid(filtering). But message about new feature developed, I want to keep.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate release notes from `git log` messages, there's [any number of tools available](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=git+release+notes+from+logs&t=ffsb&ia=web) to do that. [`git-release-notes`](https://github.com/ariatemplates/git-release-notes) for example.

Most require that the logs are written in a certain format for the result to make any sense. You can rewrite your logs with the `reword` feature of an [interactive rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History).

Comment: I will check it.
Thanks